# How to extract objects of same type from a python list and append them to new list?

Tags: python-3.x

How to extract objects of same type from a list and append them into a new list ?

```
>>> a = [ 1, 'Hi', 2, 5, 'Hello World' ]
>>> print(change(a), "str")
['Hi', 'Hello World']
```

Comment: Can you please show your code that you tried?

Comment: [i for i in a if type(i)==float or type(i)==str]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or even shorter,

```
a = [1, 'Hi', 2, 5, 'Hello World', 0.314]

def change(iterable, result_type):

    return [item for item in iterable if isinstance(item, result_type)]

print(change(a, str)) # not "str" with quotes
print(change(a, (str, float)))
```

Output:

```
 ['Hi', 'Hello World']
 ['Hi', 'Hello World', 0.314]
```

About the function 'isinstance':

> Signature: isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple, /)
>
> Docstring: 
>   Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass
>   thereof A tuple, as in "isinstance(x, (A, B, ...))", may be given 
>   as the target to check against. This is equivalent to "isinstance(x, A)
>   or isinstance(x, B) or ..." etc.

As a result, you do not have to iterate over the types explicitly to judge
if it should be added to the new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to test the type required:

```
from typing import Union, Tuple

a = [1, 'Hi', 2, 5, 'Hello World', 0.314]


def change(input_list: list,
           result_type: Union[type, Tuple[Union[type, tuple], ...]]) -> list:
    result = list()
    for e in input_list:
        if isinstance(e, result_type):
            result.append(e)
    return result


print(change(a, str))
print(change(a, (str, float)))
```

**Output:**

```
['Hi', 'Hello World']
['Hi', 'Hello World', 0.314]
```